# How can I use variable have different type as function input

Tags: c

I have several data structures which all contain a same data structure inside

```
struct numbers{
    int num_a;
    int num_b;
};

struct var_a{
    numbers num;
    //other variables
};

struct var_b{
    numbers num;
    //other variables
};
```

Now I wants to write a single function to access struct numbers in all these structures(use +1 in my example below for demonstration purpose).
One way is to use void pointer input and then cast to `struct number` inside the function:

```
void foo(void* p_input)
{
   ((numbers*)p_input)->num.num_a += 1;
} 

int main()
{
   var_a a;
   var_b b;
   foo(&a);
   foo(&b);

   return 0;
}
```

But this method requires struct numbers put at the top of structure var_a/var_b/var_c.
Another way is to use a macro instead of a function:

```
#define foo(type_t, input) \
  do{ \
      ((type_t*)input)->num.num_a += 1; \
  while(0)

int main()
{
   var_a a;
   var_b b;
   foo(typeof(a), &a);
   foo(typeof(a), &b);

   return 0;
}
```

But since my actual operation is much more complex than num_a += 1, I prefer not to use a macro.
Is there any way I can use a function to achieve my requirement?
Below I have pseudo-code which uses typeof as the function input but I suppose it is not valid in C.

```
void foo(void* p_input, type_t input_type)
{
   ((input_type*)p_input)->num.num_a += 1;
} 

int main()
{
   var_a a;
   var_b b;
   foo(a, typeof(a));
   foo(b, typeof(b));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not pass `&a.num` and `&b.num` to the function?

Comment: Don't use the first way - it invokes undefined behaviour because it makes assumptions about the memory layout of the structures.

Comment: Not shown in my sample code but actually my function will modify struct a or b, depends on the result of a.num or b.num, so I need to input a or b to the function.

Comment: I think you need to rethink.  You should have different functions for different types, and call the right function for the type you're processing.

Comment: Extract the common piece into a new struct then use a pointer in each of those other structs to the common struct.  I.e. base and derived class from oo.  You also combine into into one struct and use an union for each of distinct parts.

Comment: @SoftwareBug, Notice `var_a` is not defined,  `struct var_a` is defined.  Are you using a C compiler?

Comment: @SoftwareBug, "then cast to `struct number`".  Did you mean `struct numbers`?

Comment: Please post the actual C code, not pseudo code or C++ code.

Comment: You basically have two options: (1) require that `numbers` is always the first element of the structures (this makes sense if there is e.g. a header/payload relationship) or (2) pass the `numbers` structure to the function (that element must then be identified in the specific structure when calling the function).